# The closure in the discrete/trivial topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to determine if the two statements below are true or false:

> 1. In the discrete topology $\overline{Y} = Y$, for all $Y ⊆ X$.
> 2. In the trivial topology $\overline{Y} = X$, for all $Y ⊆ X$.

How does knowing the topology help us here? Doesn't it only tell us what subsets are open, but how does that relate to the closure?

Comment: In the discrete topology, all sets are closed. In the indiscrete topology, only $\emptyset$ and $X$ are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the open stes, then you know the closed sets, since they are the complements of the open sets.

a) It is true, since every set is open and therefore every set is closed.

b) It is false (unless $X$ turns out to be the empty set), since $\overline\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Comment: b) holds in case $X$ has one point, right?

Comment: @GEdgar No. If $X\neq\emptyset$, $\overline\emptyset=\emptyset\neq X$.

Comment: @GEdgar But it will work if you assume $Y$ is nonempty.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Indeed.

Comment: Why does every set being closed mean that the closure of a set is equal to the set? Is it because the intersection of closed sets is closed?

Comment: no basically because the intersection of all closed sets containing the set is then the set itself (a priori it might be bigger, but since you know the set itself is closed ...)